# Entity Framework and Postgres citext type

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, mapping

I'm using EF 6 with Postgres with Model from Database.
Some of my tables are with 'citext' ( case insensitive text ) which EF does not recognize.
I've mapped them in model by hand but is not too comfortable to do it.

Is it possible to introduce 'citext' and map it to String in EF and skip editing edmx files.

Comment: Have you seen this - https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/170 ?